# WKWebView Print Response Headers in Swift 2

Tags: printing, header, wkwebview

How can I see the response headers from a WKWebView loadRequest ?

eg

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.anywebsite.com")!
let urlRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
wkWebView.loadRequest(urlRequest)
```

then print the headers in the response.

Answer (score 3):

You have to assign wkWebView.navigationDelegate.

In the navigationDelegate's methods that provide a WKNavigationResponse, you can cast navigationResponse.response as a NSHTTPURLResponse to access navigationResponse.response.allHeaderFields.

Comment: WKNavigationDelegate doesn't have any method with WKNavigationResponse

Comment: optional func webView(_ webView: WKWebView,        decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse,        decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void)   https://developer.apple.com/reference/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455643-webview

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5

```
    // MARK: - WKNavigationDelegate

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationResponse: WKNavigationResponse) async -> WKNavigationResponsePolicy {
    let URLResponse = navigationResponse.response as? HTTPURLResponse
    URLResponse?.allHeaderFields.forEach({ key, value in
        print("decidePolicyFor key: ", key)
        print("decidePolicyFor value: ", value)
    })
    
    return .allow
}
```